# Why no locally trivial stratification in $C^1$ sense of Whitney's four sheets example

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

I am reading this paper [https://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/pdf/MatherBio.pdf](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Egoresky/pdf/MatherBio.pdf) from Mark Goresky. He talked about an example on page 5 saying that

> The first example is an algebraic subset of Euclidean space such that no decomposition into smooth manifolds will be locally trivial in the $C^1$ sense. The variety
> $$xy(y − x)(y − zx) = 0 $$
> consists of four ”sheets” meeting along the $z$ axis. Three of the sheets are simply a product with the z axis, but the fourth sheet twists around the axis. Any differentiable flow in the ambient Euclidan space, parallel to the $z$ axis, that preserves the first three sheets cannot preserve the fourth, because the derivative at any point on the $z$ axis is determined by the cross-ratio. So the homogeneity that is apparent in this example can only be realized by a continuous flow.

I don't understand what he means by saying that "the derivative at any point on the z axis is determined by the cross-ratio". Why there is no differentiable flow but only continous flow?